How to set up my complex filter with zoompan and xfade for ffmpeg using Fluent-FFmpeg .complexFilter method?
I'm using fluent-ffmpeg with Node.js. My problem is the setup of my complex filter.
const filters = Array.from({ length: imageCount - 1 }).map((_, i) => {
        const rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1

        return {
            zoompanFilter1: {
                filter: 'zoompan',
                options: {
                    z: 'min(zoom+0.001,1.3)',
                    d: `${imageDuration * 60}`, 
                    x: `iw/2-iw*(1/2-${rndInt}/100)*iw/zoom`, 
                    y: `ih/2-ih*(1/2-${rndInt}/100)*ih/zoom`, 
                    s: '1080x1920', // Output size
                    fps: '60'
                },
                inputs: `[${i}:v]`,
                outputs: `zoomed${i}`
            },
            zoompanFilter2: {
                filter: 'zoompan',
                options: {
                    z: 'min(zoom+0.001,1.3)', 
                    d: `${imageDuration * 60}`, 
                    x: 'iw/2-iw*(1/2-33/100)*iw/zoom',
                    y: 'ih/2-ih*(1/2-33/100)*ih/zoom',
                    s: '1080x1920', // Output size
                    fps: '60'
                },
                inputs: [`${i + 1}:v`],
                outputs: `zoomed${i + 1}`
            },
            xfadeFilter: {
                filter: 'xfade',
                options: {
                    transition: 'fade', // Crossfade transition effect
                    duration: '0.5', // Duration of crossfade in seconds
                    offset: `${imageDuration - 1}` // Offset to start the crossfade
                },
                inputs: [`zoomed${i + 1}`, `zoomed${i}`],
                outputs: `crossfaded${i}`
            },
        };
    });

This is my complete code:
async function createVideo() {
    // Escape file paths for Windows
    const videoPath = path.resolve(__dirname+ '/output.mp4').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
    const audioPath = path.resolve(__dirname+ '/output.mp3').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
    const backgroundMusicPath = path.resolve(__dirname+ '/background-music.mp3').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');

    const command = ffmpeg();

    const imagesDir = path.join(__dirname, 'images');
    const images = fs.readdirSync(imagesDir)
        .filter(file => /.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/i.test(file)) // Filter image files
        .sort() // Sort filenames to ensure the correct order
        .map(file => path.join(imagesDir, file));

        images.map((image) => command.input(image))

    const imageCount = images.length;
    const audioDuration = await getAudioDurationInSeconds(audioPath);
    const imageDuration =  Math.round(audioDuration / imageCount)

    const filters = Array.from({ length: imageCount - 1 }).map((_, i) => {
        const rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1

        return {
            zoompanFilter1: {
                filter: 'zoompan',
                options: {
                    z: 'min(zoom+0.001,1.3)', // Reset zoom to 1.0
                    d: `${imageDuration * 60}`, // Duration of the zoom effect
                    x: `iw/2-iw*(1/2-${rndInt}/100)*iw/zoom`, // Center x
                    y: `ih/2-ih*(1/2-${rndInt}/100)*ih/zoom`, // Center y
                    s: '1080x1920', // Output size
                    fps: '60'
                },
                inputs: `[${i}:v]`,
                outputs: `zoomed${i}`
            },
            zoompanFilter2: {
                filter: 'zoompan',
                options: {
                    z: 'min(zoom+0.001,1.3)', // Reset zoom to 1.0
                    d: `${imageDuration * 60}`, // Duration of the zoom effect
                    x: 'iw/2-iw*(1/2-33/100)*iw/zoom', // Center x
                    y: 'ih/2-ih*(1/2-33/100)*ih/zoom', // Center y
                    s: '1080x1920', // Output size
                    fps: '60'
                },
                inputs: [`${i + 1}:v`],
                outputs: `zoomed${i + 1}`
            },
            xfadeFilter: {
                filter: 'xfade',
                options: {
                    transition: 'fade', // Crossfade transition effect
                    duration: '0.5', // Duration of crossfade in seconds
                    offset: `${imageDuration - 1}` // Offset to start the crossfade
                },
                inputs: [`zoomed${i + 1}`, `zoomed${i}`],
                outputs: `crossfaded${i}`
            },
        };
    });

    command
    .input(audioPath)
    .input(backgroundMusicPath)
    .outputOptions([
        '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
        '-c:v', 'libx264',
        '-c:a', 'aac',
        '-y',
        '-t', `${audioDuration}`,
        '-r', '60',
        '-s', '1080x1920',
        '-preset', 'ultrafast',
        '-map', '[final_video]',
        '-map', '[mixed_audio]',
    ])
    .complexFilter([
        // Apply zoompan filters and xfade transitions
        ...filters.flatMap(({ zoompanFilter1, zoompanFilter2, xfadeFilter }) => [
            zoompanFilter1,
            zoompanFilter2,
            xfadeFilter,
        ]),
        {
            filter: 'concat',
            options: {
                n: imageCount - 1, // Number of videos to concatenate
                v: 1, // Video streams
                a: 0 // No audio streams
            },
            inputs: filters.map((_, i) => `crossfaded${i}`),
            outputs: 'video_sequence'
        },
        {
            filter: 'curves',
            options: 'preset=increase_contrast',
            inputs: 'video_sequence',
            outputs: 'curves'
        },
        {
            filter: 'subtitles',
            options: `./subtitles.ass:fontsdir=./fonts/:force_style='FontName=Montserrat Black Italic,FontSize=17,MarginL=10,MarginV=25,Alignment=10,Spacing=0.2,Outline=0.1,Shadow=1.5'`,
            inputs: '[curves]',
            outputs: 'final_video'
        },
        {
            filter: 'volume',
            options: 0.3,  // Adjust the volume to 25% of the original
            inputs: `${imageCount + 1}:a`,
            outputs: 'background_music_adjusted'
        },
        // Apply the amix filter to mix the two audio inputs
        {
            filter: 'amix',
            options: {
                inputs: 2,
                duration: 'first',
                dropout_transition: 0,
                weights: '1 0.25',
                normalize: 0
            },
            inputs: [`${imageCount}:a`, 'background_music_adjusted'],
            outputs: 'mixed_audio'
        },
      ])
    .save(videoPath)
    .on('progress', function(progress) {
        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done');
      })
    .on('end', function(stdout, stderr) {
        // emptyFolder(imagesDir)
        console.log('Transcoding succeeded !');
      }) 
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.error('Une erreur s\'est produite :', err.message);
    });
}

My problem is I see the 1 image then the transition and i see the 2 image. After that I'm supposed to see the 3 image but I see the 2 image.
What am I doing wrong?
I tried switching the inputs: [`zoomed${i + 1}`, `zoomed${i}`] to inputs: [`zoomed${i}`, `zoomed${i+1}`] but it just showed the next image and not a loop of consecutive images.
